# FixedToolWindow appears as floating bar when ShowInTaskbar is false - how can I stop this?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using a WinForm configured as a FixedToolWindow.  I've set ShowInTaskbar to be False - I'm using a NotifyIcon to manage restoring the window, once it's been minimized.

When I minimize the window, it becomes a bar in the bottom left corner of the primary screen - a window title bar, I'm guessing.  I can move it and if I then restore the window and re-minimize it, it returns to the new position.  If I set ShowInTaskbar to True, it disappears on minimize.

How can I stop it from appearing as this bar when ShowInTaskbar is False?  When minimized, I want the NotifyIcon to be the only visible artefact of its existence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `Form.Hide()` and `Form.Show()` methods instead of minimizing/restoring the `WindowState` and leave the `ShowInTaskBar` property to `true`.

Comment: Show and Hide were give me the behaviour I wanted.  Thanks very much.